# Date() object outside loop keeps changing

Tags: javascript

I have the code

```
var someObject = ObjectCreator(); //function that is out of my control
```

`someObject` contains a field `startDate` which is a Date object.
I want to replicate the object so that the date is a week later in each object. Each replica should then be put in an array. So I have...

```
var someArray = [];
var startDate = someObject.startdate;

for (i=1; i<4; i++) {
  var newobject = someObject;
  newobject.startdate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + (i*7));
  someArray.push(newobject);
}
```

what I notice is that `startDate` increases within the loop. I want it to remain the same. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `setDate` is mutating it, isn't it?

Comment: Do not set it contingent to loop progress then .

Comment: You need to create a date object on each loop iteration.

Comment: newobject.startdate = someObject.startdate = startDate

They are all the same...

Comment: is there a way to make them not influence each other but have the same contents?

Comment: @seamusgalla yes, you will have to clone it before you modify the object. Search on stackoverflow on how to clone object in javascript

Comment: @Long Nguyen Thanks this is what I needed. I didn't realize that java script didn't create a copy every time you said something was `=`

Answer (score 3):

Because `setDate()` change `startdate`. This should work:

```
var todaysDate = new Date();
var someArray = [];

for (i=1; i<4; i++) {
  var newobject = {
      name: "jim",
      startdate: new Date(),
  }

  newobject.startdate.setDate(todaysDate.getDate() + (i*7));
  someArray.push(newobject);
}
```

Comment: I edited my question for clarity. I cannot keep declaring the `startdate` field as you have suggested.